# I can't send data from the server

Tags: java, printwriter

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(nsocket.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(nsocket.getOutputStream()),true);

list.clear();
while ((data=br.readLine())!=null){
    list.add(data);
}

br.close();
if (list.size() >= 2) {
    lat =  list.get(0);
    log =  list.get(1);
    route =  list.get(2);
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            activity.client.setText(lat);
            activity.client1.setText(log);
        }
    });
    activity.mydb.updateData(lat, log, route);
}   else {
    parentroute = list.get(0);
    Cursor res = activity.mydb.getData(parentroute);
    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        latitude = res.getString(0);
        longitude = res.getString(1);
    }

    out.println(latitude);
    out.println(longitude);
    out.flush();
    out.close();


    nsocket.close();
}
```

I can receive the data.But I cant send the data using Printwriter.Using this code I can retrive data from the database using Cursor.But the retrived data can't send to the client.

Comment: What happens when you try? Do you get an Exception?

Comment: I didn't get the data in client side

Answer (score 1):

Closing the `BufferedReader` closes the `InputStreamReader` closes the `InputStream`  closes the `Socket`. Close the `BufferedReader` after you wrote the data.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible problems:

1 - you are reading from the socket until the input stream is closed - are you sure the client is only closing his output and not the whole socket (connection)?

2 - see [J. Tennié's asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41800312/85421), that is, when you close the input `br.close();` the socket also get closed and you will not be able to send over it. See documentation of [getInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream--):

> Closing the returned InputStream will close the associated socket.

Hint/note: There is no exceptions being thrown since the methods of `PrintWriter` never throw any I/O exception. I recommend not to use that class if you want to be informed of any exception, or, at least, check if there was an error - method `checkError()`. See [javadoc PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html):

> Methods in this class never throw I/O exceptions, although some of its constructors may. The client may inquire as to whether any errors have occurred by invoking `checkError()`.

Comment: I am fresher in programming.I think when the output socket close the whole socket connection lose.